# Why does water purify?

Tags: taamei-mitzvot-reasons, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, mikvah-ritual-bath, water

The Torah states that immersion in a mikveh of water purifies a person from *Tuma* (spiritual impurity). Why does water do this? Is there some kind of spiritual powers imbued in water?

Or is this just a decree of the torah without a reason?

Please source.

Answer (score 11):

[R Aryeh Kaplan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aryeh_Kaplan) in his beautiful book [Waters of Eden](http://a.co/cTXMS8l) (also part of his [Anthology vol. 2](http://a.co/8oMKnhf)) writes this is a *chok* (law without explicit reasons) and cites [Bamidbar Rabbah 19:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Bemidbar_Rabbah.19.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> By your lives, a dead person doesn't make things impure, and the
> water doesn't make things pure. Rather, God said: I have engraved a
> rule, I have decreed a decree (chukah chakakti, gezeira gazarti), and
> you have no permission to transgress what I decreed, as it says "This
> is a chok (rule) of the Torah."

He then goes on to provide some explanations, knowing full well they are only an incomplete picture and the full rationale is beyond the human intellect.

- **Water** is a cleansing agent. The same way we wash with **water**, we also purify with **water**
- He describes at length how a *mikve* is like a womb and how one emerges "anew" from the *mikve*. Like a womb is full of **water**, so a *mikve*
- By placing himself in the **water** of the *mikve*, a person enters a place where he cannot breathe, therefore cannot live. When emerging from **water**, he is like born again (incidentally, he writes this is one of the reasons a *mikve* as to be directly in the ground, like a grave)
- He describes **water** as the ultimate fluid, the substance that most represents change and unstability (see [Bereshit 49:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.49.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)), while earth is stability and permanence. Until God brought **water** in the world, no life or change was possible. **Water** is life, earth is death (and thus we return to earth after death). When immersing in a *mikve*, one spiritually immerses in the basic concept of change itself, nullifies one's ego (which represents our permanence) and emerges renewed and re-birthed. **Water** represents change, and therefore that no evil is ineradicable, and no sin unforgivable ("repentance can wash away any sin"). **Water** therefore represents spiritual cleansing
- He has a long section on the analogy between *mikve* and the **water** of the river from Eden (i.e., **water** as the primary connection to *Gan Eden*) - too long to summarize here - see original if you are interested

The above summary is a very inadequate representation of R Aryeh Kaplan's beautiful words - you should read the original for yourself.

Comment: isnt water supposed to represent the sefira of chesed or something like that?

Comment: so it's a chok but has reasons isnt that  a contradiction?

Comment: he writes explanations, i.e., we don't know the full reasons but can try and explain - he writes explicitly what I write in first para after quote: it is only an incomplete picture

Comment: you are saying what water does and represents and giving a nice summary of that book but the reasons u give dont answer what water is, i.e. is there some kind of spiritual power imbued in water that give it the power to do all these things etc. looking for a more fundamental reason

Comment: I think that the answer to your question is in the midrash quote. It is not water that makes things pure. Water is only the mechanism God uses to effect spiritual change. Water per se is nothing. R Akiva Tatz says it is no coincidence that in many languages water means What? (Water/What in English, Wasser in German/was is what, acqua in Italian/qua is what). Therefore one cannot say what water *is*, only what it *does*

Comment: according to this water is chesed - http://www.inner.org/sefirot/sefchesd.htm

Comment: @ray -- How about "overall it's a choq, but there are elements we can take lessons from". What kind of force water might have, and whether metaphysical forces and pyschological impact are even separable things (do human attitudes drive metaphysics?) are far harder questions. And for all our exploring, will remain choq.

Comment: @ray didn't they say that Shlomo was able to find the reasons for all Chukim (except Para Aduma). All mitzvot have reasons, and no mitzva is contingent on its reasons